# VB.NET MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can Visual Studio natively connect to a MySQL database or do I need to install a 3rd party connector first? Could someone please provide a small code example either way? I can't seem to make this work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can Visual Studio natively connect to
>   a MySQL database?

Based upon my knowledge, no.

> Do I need to install a 3rd party
>   connector first?

Yes, ***[MySQL has their own .NET Connector.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html)***

> Could someone please provide a small
>   code example either way? I can't seem
>   to make this work.

[Here is the link to the MySQL Connector documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html).

In there, I found this example:

```
Imports System.Data

Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Tutorial1
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=******;"
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...")
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        End Try
        conn.Close()
        Console.WriteLine("Done.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the MySQL .NET connector from the following link

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

and view a previous C# related answer of mine here:

[Connecting to a Mysql DB with C# - Need some with Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471482/connecting-to-a-mysql-db-with-c-need-some-with-datasets/4471968#4471968)

Sorry I dont have a VB related one but I'm sure you'd find plenty of examples here or on the web :P