# I got error when to connect MySQL vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I don't know how it works with MySQL. My problem is I can't connect to my SQL Database. I don't know if I put the code correctly or not because I already researched, there are a lot opinion how to put the code but there is no code for Visual Studio 2017.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class FormDatabaseMySQL

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=bukuakaunrumah")
Dim command As New SqlCommand

Private Sub FormDatabaseMySQL_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



End Sub

Private Sub ButtonBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonBack.Click
    Me.Hide()
    FormFront.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmit.Click
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO `accountinfo`(`AccountID`, `AccountName`, `AccountPassword`) VALUES (@accountID,@accountName,@accountPassword)", connection)

    command.Parameters.Add("@AccountID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxID.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@AccountName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxName.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@AccountPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxPassword.Text

    connection.Open()

    If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

        MessageBox.Show("Successful Registered", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error")


    End If
    connection.Close()


End Sub 
End Class
```

This is my output. [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwMKM.png)

**EDIT:**
It displays error: [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqBkZ.png)

**EDIT 2:**
I still has error even I already downloaded MySQL Connector[image: Figure 3]

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is for **Microsoft SQL Server** exclusively - it won't work with MySQL - you need to find the right namespace and classes (`MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`) to work with MySQL

Comment: I already changed it. But I got error.

Comment: You ought not create one connection to use everywhere.  There is also nothing reusable about a DB Command object.  Those should both be created, used and disposed of as you need them.  A Global connection string is fine.  `But I got error` is a useless problem description.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: @Plutonix I don't want to have any argue with you but I'm really need help to improve myself. I hope you will understand my situation that I'm having right now.

Comment: If you want a good answer you need to ask a good question and provide enough info for someone to be able to help.  `But I got error` is useless.  Would you call your mechanic and tell them `my car has a problem`?? There other comment were **entirely** towards helping you write better code - the code you have is leaking resources and the public command object is not used since you create a `new` one each time.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: oh ya, for that statement, I already uploaded the problem which I'm having right now because I don't know how to explain it. Btw, thank you to advice to read the How to Ask and the tour.

Comment: Pictures of errors or code in posts are bad because future users cannot search pictures.  Besides it is easier to copy-paste `type mySQLCOnnection is not defined` than to do it with a screen shot.  Besides downloading the assembly, you need to include it in the project.  If you use NuGet it does this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Data.SqlClient namespace is the.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.
If you try connect MySQL DB it's better to use :

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

And connect like this :

```
Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
Dim myConnectionString as String

myConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
            & "uid=root;" _
            & "pwd=;" _
            & "database=bukuakaunrumah"

Try
  conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
  conn.Open()

Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

PS : try replace "datasource" with "server" in your connexion configuration

Comment: It still show errors. there are not coding 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' .and others too...

Comment: There is no suggestion for MySql and others.

Comment: @Zuhrain It don't work because the function that he used is part of the 3rd party MySQL NET Connector. You need to install it first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install the MySQL NET Connector.

You can find it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

You can find the Documentation for it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) and the Reference List [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/R_Project_ConnectorNET.htm).

Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190631/9290012) if you want to see a code example.

Comment: I already edited the post. as you can see, it still different. I thing I have missing something but I already downloaded the MySQL Connector.

Comment: You still need to add the library to you project. As you can see: the import lines are underlined in green. That means that you did not add it correctly.

Comment: can you show me how to add the library because I can't found it.

Comment: Links to elsewhere are not an answer.  They are instructions *where* the OP can find the answer9s)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18831708)