# How to connect to the MySQL database from an IP?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wamp

I installed a VM on the internal network of our company.

I use Wamp to host a website so that it can be accessed by other members of the company.

But I would like to know how to access the MySQL base wamp directly from an IP to run a VB script.

Indeed, on my VB file I put this to connect:

```
con.ConnectionString = "DRIVER = {MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & "SERVER = localhost;" & "DATABASE = mydatabase;" & "UID = root; PWD =; OPTION = 3"
```

I opened the ports of the VM and added in the file `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\my.ini` the line:

```
bind-address = [my_server_ip]
```

But it doesn't connect. What else should I do?

Comment: You should work with the MySQL NET Connector. You can find it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

You can find the Documentation for it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) and the Reference List [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/R_Project_ConnectorNET.htm).


Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190631/9290012) if you want to see a code example.

Comment: 1) Change `localhost` to the ip address of the VM 2) Setup a user account in MySQL that is allowed to connect from a remote IP address. By default `root` is only allowed to connect from the machine running MySQL 3) Use this new MySQL account in your VB code to connect.

Comment: ___PS___ Dont change `root` to be allowed to connect from a remote IP. Thats a major security Boob

Comment: Thank you  RiggsFoll, I changed the username of the database and it worked !

Comment: @Rocstar Yes, it works with the ODBC 3.51 Driver, but it is really old with many issues and you shouldn't use it. Use the native .Net driver instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ODBC driver, install [MySql.Data from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/6.10.6) in your project by following these steps:

- Right-click on your project in **Solution Explorer**
- From the context menu, select **Manage NuGet Packages**
- In **NuGet Package Manager**, click on the **Browse** tab
- Search for **MySql.Data** (by Oracle)
- In the search results, select **MySql.Data** (by Oracle)
- Click on the **Install** button to install the latest version (6.10.6 at time of writing this answer)

Installing NuGet Packages is the recommended way as it makes it much easier to manage your packages and keep them up-to-date, but if don't want to do it, you can download he package either from the NuGet link above, or directly from [Oracle's website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), extract the MySql.Data.dll file, place it in your bin folder and add a reference to it in your project.

Either way, now you have your project using the MySql.Data driver, change your connection string to:

```
"DefaultDB": "Server=127.0.0.0;Database=mydatabase;User ID=;Password=;"
```

Change the IP to the one for your VM, and of course your database name, username, and password.

Note: as others mentioned in the comments, granting `root` remote access poses a great risk to your database. It is better to create a restricted account and grant it remote access, then use this account in your connection string.

Comment: `root` in WAMPServer is normally only allowed to connect from the machine running MySQL. Bit more secure if you create a new account in MySQL that is allowed to connect remotely and only give it access to the specific database you want the VB code to access. Or maybe go as far as only allowing access to the specific table(s) in a database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Completely agree. I will update my answer to mention that.