# How to open connection simultaneously with multiple connection?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do I change connection and execute some query in my form load during run time? it's more like opening multiple connections simultaneously but how do I do that?

**Example of the Database info:**

[image: Example of the Database info]

EDIT: I do have the Query but I don't know how to open the other connection during run time. the structure of their database is the same so there's no problem when executing the query. The problem is just how do I change the connection during runtime without pressing anything.

Comment: What database? Microsoft SQLServer?

Comment: @Christoph I'm using MYSQL

Comment: I usually create a property that returns an open connection - always the same if not broken but one for each thread (using a threadstatic field to cache the variable).

Comment: To open a connection, you need a connection string. You need more than one connection strings if you want to connect to multiple databases. Each database requires a specific connection string.

Comment: See [VB.NET MySQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190599/vb-net-mysql-connection). Just use different variables for your different connections.

Comment: how do i change it during run time and execute query without pressing anything? @RobertBaron

Comment: Please show the form load code.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I thought you like to execute queries in parallel. Use a 2nd connection then. Create a new connection with the new connection string. This is a usual use case for copying data between different installations. You need one to read from and one to write to.

Comment: Check this http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?858355-RESOLVED-Bulk-copy-table-from-MySQL-to-Access-accd  Answer compliments of our own @jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jmcilhinney answer in an external forum. The adapter is using one connection for the Select and another connection for the Insert. The trick is setting the .AcceptChangesDuringFill to False The default changes the Added to Unchanged.

```vb
Private Sub UpdateADifferentDatabase()
    Using cnSource As New MySqlConnection("First connection string"), cnDestination As New MySqlConnection("Second connection string")
        Using selectCommand As New MySqlCommand("Select statement here", cnSource), insertCommand As New MySqlCommand("Insert statement here ", cnDestination)
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                da.SelectCommand = selectCommand
                da.InsertCommand = insertCommand
                'The following allows the .DataRowState to remain as Added (normally it is changed to Unchanged by the .Fill method)
                da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                da.Update(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: what if i add a new client ? should i recode it again?