# COMException including Excel during ADO connection

Tags: mysql, excel, vb.net, visual-studio, ado

Ok, i don't know if it will be useful but i want to share. Modos and admin will delete if they want.

I'm developping a VB application (actually, i migrate one from Excel VBA) to interact with MySQL Database.
I use VS 2019 16.8.2, Windows 7 x64.

I got a cryptic issue during connection to the database (using ADO, reference used: MS ADO 2.6).
Here's the code:

```
    Public Sub test_connect()

            Dim server_name As String
            Dim database_name As String
            Dim login_database As String
            Dim port_number As String
            Dim pwd_database As String
    
            server_name = "my_server"
            database_name = "my_database"
            login_database = "whoisyourdaddy"
            pwd_database = "youare"
    
            connexion_dlweb_doc = New ADODB.Connection With {
                .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};" _
            & "SERVER=" & server_name & "; " _
            & "PORT=" & port_number & "; " _
            & "DATABASE=" & database_name & "; " _
            & "UID=" & login_database & "; " _
            & "PWD=" & pwd_database & "; " _
            & "OPTION=3"
            }
 
            If connexion_dlweb_doc.State <> adStateOpen Then
                connexion_dlweb_doc.Open()
            End If
        End Sub
```

So, i got an exception with the " connexion_dlweb_doc = New ADODB.Connection" command. It's where it becomes cryptic:
*System.TypeInitializationException : 'The type initializer for 'MyAPP.mod_declaration_variables' threw an exception.'
COMException : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Classe non enregistrée (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).*

mod_declaration_variables is a module where i declare global variables like *connexion_dlweb_doc*:

```
Public connexion_dlweb_doc As ADODB.Connection
```

So, i asked my best friend google about this cryptic message and the CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} refer to...Microsoft.Interop.Excel 14.0.0.0
I use the reference *MS Excel Objet Library 14.0* in my project. How did this interact with the ADO connection part? What's the link? Why the code crash here and not before?
I don't know why but the solution was to delete (or comment) every variable declaration using Excel library, e.g:
`Public xlApp_arbo_wiki As Excel.Application`

Guess it would help noobs like me.

Comment: Did you consider using [SQLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190631/12666543) instead of ADO connection

Comment: Use OleDb to connect to Excel and MySqlConnection to connect to MySql. ADODB is obsolete.

Comment: @XingyuZhao an SqlConnection is a connection from System.Data..SqlClient and is part of ADO.net framework. I would doubt that you could use an SqlConnection successfully with either MySql or Excel.

Comment: See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/